# JQuery: Simplest way to add line breaks to multiple matching results

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, swift, wkwebview

As part of an iPhone app that uses WKWebView I load Jquery (version 2.2.3) and execute the following code that retrieves all the `div` elements of an HTML that match a given class name e.g. `test`:

```
$('div.test').text()
```

Using the following callback `completionHandler` written in swift, the result of executing this produces:

```
func completionHandler(result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) {
    if let result = result as? String {
        print(result)
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
 result1result2result3
```

but instead I need:

```
result1
result2
result3
```

Now I'd like to append a line break to every matching element. I have tried doing the following without success:

```
$('div.test').text().append('\n')
```

or

```
$('div.test').text().join('\n')
```

Is there a simple one liner no embedded function approach to appending line breaks to each result so it can be parseable from the swift side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a lot of trial/error this produces the desired results:

```
$('div.test').map(function() { return $(this).text().concat('\\n'); }).get().toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` function to reduce an array to, for example, a string.

```
$('div.test').toArray().reduce(function(previous, current){
    return previous+'\n'+current
})
```